# What would be the impact of changing Forms Authentication Node in web.config

Tags: .net, forms, authentication, web-config

We have typical .NET forms authentication, as per following web.config node.

I wish to change it from

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="login/logon.aspx" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" timeout="60000" slidingExpiration="true"/>
    </authentication>
```

to

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="login/logon.aspx" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" name=".CUSTOMNAME" timeout="60000" slidingExpiration="true"/>
    </authentication>
```

What could be the possible impact? IIS would be reset anyways.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name specifies the HTTP cookie to use for authentication. By default, the value of name is .ASPXAUTH. If multiple applications are running on a single server and each application requires a unique cookie, you must configure the cookie name in each application's Web.config file.
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Possible impact: Already authenticated users will need to login again.

Comment: Thanks! If that's the only possible impact then we can do it after business hours